# CPU spiking in Win2003 server with High NDM activity

Tags: windows, cpu, file-transfer

We have a Win2003 server, where we receive files through NDM and at any time, we would be receiving 6 files from different sources. The CPU on this server is always > 95%, which causes all the componenets to slow down and the server is hung once in every 2 days. We have the latest McAfee running on the server. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Server Fault question. My gut instinct would be to look at McAfee. Use a tool like [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out what exactly is taking your cycles.

Comment: Thaanks. The question is posted at ServerFault.